# SED or AWK command that print the value between two patterns

Tags: unix

I have a pattern as below:

GET /abcd/efgh/ijkl?_id=1234567890&param=&param1=

_id is always the same but the word param can change. I am trying to print the value which is between _id= and first occurrence of & . I am using my command as below but whenever param changes, the result is not printed as expected.

cat test.txt | grep “/abcd/efgh/ijkl” | sed -e 's/.*id=(.*)&.*/\1/'

Actual Result:
Prints the whole line

Expected Result:
1234567890

Comment: `sed -e 's/.id=\(.*\)\&.*/\1/` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{print $2}' file 
1234567890
```